# Azure stream analytics - How to redirect or handle error events/rows?

Tags: azure, cortana-intelligence, azure-stream-analytics

Is there a way to capture and redirect data error events/rows to a separate output?

For example, say I have events coming through and for some reason there are data conversion errors. I would like to handle those errors and do something, probably a separate output for further investigation?

Currently in stream analytics error policy, if an event fails to be written to output we only got two options

Drop - which just drops the event (or)
Retry - retries writing the event until it succeeds

Comment: did you tried to output to blob storage? this usually can handle all outputs, you can do that first, and see how the output looks like, and than change it back to the original desired output

Answer (score 0):

Collecting all error events is not supported currently. You can enable diagnostic logs and get a a sample of every kind of error at frequent intervals.
[Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/monitoring-and-diagnostics/monitoring-overview-of-diagnostic-logs) is the documentation link.

If there is a way for you to filter such events in the query itself, then you could redirect such events to a different output and reprocess that later.